# If I draw x number of faces of dimension m from an n-cube without replacement, what is the probability that all 2^n vertices are drawn at least once?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

The number of m-dimensional faces in an n-cube equals $E_{n,m} = 2^{n-m} \binom {n}{m}$. Each vertex appears in the following number of m-faces: $E_v = \binom {n}{m}$. Consequently, the number of faces excluding any given vertex equals: $E_{V excluded} = E_{n,m} - E_v = 2^{n-m} \binom {n}{m} - \binom {n}{m}$. The probability of not drawing a specific vertex after x draws therefore equals: $P_{Vexcluded,x} = \binom {E_{V excluded}} {x} /  \binom {E_{n,m}} {x}$

However, I am struggling to generalize the above to all vertices as vertices are neither independent (any given m-face includes $2^m$ vertices) nor mutually exclusive (more than one vertex can be excluded simultaneously). Hypothetically, the probability of any vertex being excluded after x draws should be: $P_{AnyVexcluded,x} = 2^n * P_{Vexcluded,x} - P_{MultipleVexcluded,x}$

One way I have been thinking about this is that the number of faces excluding a set of y vertices equal: $E_{v,y} = E_{n,m} - y*E_v + E_{common}$ where $E_{common}$ is a function of the distance between vertices. There are $\binom {n}{l}$ vertices at a Hamiltonian distance $l$ from any given vertex. Any pair of vertices of distance $l$ will be on the same $l$ dimensional face. The number of m-faces that share a given $l$-face equals: $E_{m,l} = 2^{m-l} \binom {m}{l} * 2^{n-m} \binom {n} {m} / {2^{n-l} \binom {n} {l}} = \binom {n-l}{n-m}$. For any pair of vertices, then, $E_{common}$ = $E_{m,l}$.

Using this information, is there a way to calculate $P_{MultipleVexcluded,x}$ without calculating for all combinations of $l$ and y?